# Can I set offset in lookup of iTunes API? (I'd like to paginate lookup result)

Tags: api, itunes

I'd like to paginate lookup result. So can I set offset in lookup of iTunes API?

[The API document](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) says no offset parameter, but, in search API, we can set offset likes below.

- https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=hello&limit=2&offset=0
- https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=hello&limit=2&offset=1
- https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=hello&limit=2&offset=2

The above, we can get paginated result by 2 items.

So I thought I can do it same things in lookup API but couldn't.

- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253&entity=song&limit=2&offset=0
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253&entity=song&limit=2&offset=1
- https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253&entity=song&limit=2&offset=2

The above, we get same result. It seems offset parameter was ignored.

How can I get a paginated result of lookup API?

Comment: Really really old thread, but the same happen to me. Works with `search`, doesn't works with `lookup`