# ITunes Search API page number for the query

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes-search-api

Is there any way to get results of next page of a search query? When I give page parameter, I get the same results from ITunes as:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=us&limit=200&entity=software&term=a
and
https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=us&limit=200&entity=software&term=a&page=2

gives the same output. Giving page parameter works for customer reviews.

Is there any way to get the results of next page?

According to API documentation there is no way but I found a lot of useful answers which are not indicated in API documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually there is no pagination in apple search API. It will only return maximum first 200 records.

Below is reference URL for same:

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching

Thank you.

Comment: It may be worth trying out [@Marian Przyszedł](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593450/marian-przyszed%c5%82) 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707491/2475008). Testing `offset` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 35):

I found a way to query more records. There is a parameter called **offset**, which is not mentioned in API documentation.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=a&offset=25&limit=25
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Works great when using the search endpoint. Does not work for me for the lookup endpoint :-(

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146976/can-i-set-offset-in-lookup-of-itunes-api-id-like-to-paginate-lookup-result

Comment: Is there a way to find out how many pages there are without using trial and error?

Comment: I see offset having some effect but it behaves weirdly. For example, when using 3500 as the value, the resultCount property in the response body is 45. When I use 3600, it is 50. Does anyone have something similar?