# Retrieve all the results from App Store for certain keywords

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-sdk

I am looking at the search API provided by Itunes, however I noticed it set limit to 200 which means if there are more than 200 results to be returned it will only return 200.

What I want to realize is I want to search certain keywords and retrieve all the apps related to this keyword, is it possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following are examples of fully-qualified URLs for specific search requests:

```
•   To search for all Jack Johnson audio and video content (movies, podcasts, music, music videos, audiobooks, short films, and tv shows), your URL would look like the following:
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson

•   To search for all Jack Johnson audio and video content and return only the first 25 items, your URL would look like the following:
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&limit=25

•   To search for only Jack Johnson music videos, your URL would look like the following:
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&entity=musicVideo

•   To search for all Jim Jones audio and video content and return only the results from the Canada iTunes Store, your URL would look like the following:
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jim+jones&country=ca

•   To search for applications titled “Yelp” and return only the results from the United States iTunes Store, your URL would look like the following:
    https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software
```

Please refer to below Apple docs:

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searchexamples

To Search on iOS apps for all countries:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&entity=software&limit=200

Comment: Thanks but Apple sets the limit to 200, any workaround to get rid of the limitation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the term you're looking for is offset, and you can add this to your search parameters, to view x results after your limit of x.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&entity=software&limit=200&offset=200
```

For example, the search above will give you the next 200 results (assuming there's more results for your search of course.)

Should work for search endpoints, but not lookup endpoints according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177089/itunes-search-api-page-number-for-the-query/46707491#46707491).